# Keras conversion model using TensorFlow.js model converters.: error: unrecognized arguments: \ folder

Tags: python, keras, anaconda, tensorflow.js

I am trying to convert a Keras model to tensorflowjs using anaconda command. 
In my Root Folder I have

1. weight.h5 file
2. folder directory

I am trying to run the following command using Anaconda prompt.

```
tensorflowjs_converter --input_format keras \ weight.h5 \  folder
```

but I am getting an error

> TensorFlow.js model converters.: error: unrecognized arguments: \ folder

Please correct me if I am making any silly mistakes

Comment: `tensorflowjs_converter --input_format keras weight.h5  folder` will probably work since you are using the backlash character without the newline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the command line you should use:

```
tensorflowjs_converter --input_format keras weight.h5 folder
```

The backlash character ignore the newline and is called "line continuation character". If the statement stands on a single line, there is no need to use it.